# How to sort json string by value in a loop?

Tags: php, json, sorting

I have the following json string that I want to sort in the format A-Z.

```
{
    "buses": 
    [
            {
                "name": "Shuttle 10: City 1 - City 5 (11 seats left)",
                "id": 12
            },
            {
                "name": "Shuttle 11: City 1 - City 5 (11 seats left)",
                "id": 13
            },
            {
                "name": "Shuttle 12: City 1 - City 5 (11 seats left)",
                "id": 14
            },
            {
                "name": "Shuttle 13: City 1 - City 5 (11 seats left)",
                "id": 15
            },
            {
                "name": "Shuttle 14: City 1 - City 5 (11 seats left)",
                "id": 16
            },
            {
                "name": "Shuttle 15: City 1 - City 5 (11 seats left)",
                "id": 17
            },
            {
                "name": "Shuttle 16: City 1 - City 5 (11 seats left)",
                "id": 18
            },
            {
                "name": "Shuttle 17: City 1 - City 5 (11 seats left)",
                "id": 19
            },
            {
                "name": "Shuttle 18: City 1 - City 5 (10 seats left)",
                "id": 20
            },
            {
                "name": "Shuttle 19: City 1 - City 5 (11 seats left)",
                "id": 21
            },
            {
                "name": "Shuttle 1: City 1 - City 5 (10 seats left)",
                "id": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "Shuttle 20: City 1 - City 5 (11 seats left)",
                "id": 22
            },
            {
                "name": "Shuttle 21: City 1 - City 5 (11 seats left)",
                "id": 23
            },
            {
                "name": "Shuttle 22: City 1 - City 5 (11 seats left)",
                "id": 24
            },
            {
                "name": "Shuttle 23: City 1 - City 5 (11 seats left)",
                "id": 25
            },
            {
                "name": "Shuttle 24: City 1 - City 5 (11 seats left)",
                "id": 26
            },
            {
                "name": "Shuttle 25: City 1 - City 5 (11 seats left)",
                "id": 27
            },
            {
                "name": "Shuttle 26: City 1 - City 5 (11 seats left)",
                "id": 28
            },
            {
                "name": "Shuttle 27: City 1 - City 5 (11 seats left)",
                "id": 29
            },
            {
                "name": "Shuttle 28: City 1 - City 5 (11 seats left)",
                "id": 30
            },
            {
                "name": "Shuttle 29: City 1 - City 5 (11 seats left)",
                "id": 31
            },
            {
                "name": "Shuttle 2: City 1 - City 5 (2 seats left)",
                "id": 3
            }
        ]
}
```

So basically I want to sort the string in ascending order A-Z where the result will have this occur first:

```
{
    "name": "Shuttle 1: City 1 - City 5 (10 seats left)",
    "id": 1
}
```

And this as the last.

```
    {
        "name": "Shuttle 29: City 1 - City 5 (11 seats left)",
        "id": 31
    }
```

I have held the json string in a variable `$result` and trying the sort function does not work.

```
$json = json_decode($result, true);
echo sort($json);
```

What is the best way to achieve this using sort in php and return the sorted json string?

Comment: your json format is getting error, how could we solve,

Comment: add { at the begining and } at the end